# phpmyadmin : Din't get auto_increment property on primary key after importing database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I imported a database in phpmyadmin. 
It is a large database nearly size of 990MB.
But after importing, I have a problem.
 
All the key constraints are there, but primary key is not set to auto increment.
So when I insert data in the table it throws duplicate entry and primary key violation error.

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

It's clearly because it's inserting 0 in case auto_increment is not set 

I tried to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT by running 
`ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;`
and then tried to check the auto_increment in the id field but it is giving me this error

> Query error:
>   1062 - ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

1. check you indexing and Primary Key
2. remove indexing and Primary Key

`` ALTER TABLE  `users ` DROP PRIMARY KEY ``

3. Add Auto_increment and Add Primary Key

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

For InnoDB you cannot set the auto_increment value lower or equal to the highest current index.

> Note that you cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to >any that have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or >equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the >value is reset to the current maximum plus one. For InnoDB, if the value >is less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and >the current sequence value is not changed.

so, we can

`` ALTER TABLE  `users` ADD  `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ``

hope it work for you .

Comment: It alread has id and it's important to have all the ids. Dropping primary and and adding id again won't affect the existing id values?